# TouchID for Multi User App (Swift - Obj-C): IOS8

Tags: ios, touch-id

I am planning to develop a multi user IOS application.
I was thinking about to use the TouchID as alternative authentication.
Could it be done for multiple user?

The steps that my app have to perform are these:

- User register its data (name - surname - username - password)
- Username and password are saved to keychain.
- If the device support TouchID, the user will be asked if he/she wants to enroll.

These steps are reproduce for every user that wants to register to the application.

Is it possible to achieve this?
Have you got better ideas?

Thank you in advance.